# matplotlib: (Automatically) Ensure text fits inside figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create some violin plots and put some text over each plot. My problem is that the text sometimes gets printed outside the figure. Does matplotlib provide a way to automatically extend the y-axis if text is outside there?

Minimal example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.violinplot([1, 2, 3])

plt.gca().text(1.1, 2.5, "foo")  # Ok
plt.gca().text(1.1, 3.2, "bar")  # Outside plot
plt.gca().text(1.1, 4.0, "baz")  # Not even printed

plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify ylim:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.violinplot([1, 2, 3])

plt.gca().text(1.1, 2.5, "foo")  # Ok
plt.gca().text(1.1, 3.2, "bar")  # Outside plot
plt.gca().text(1.1, 4.0, "baz")  # Not even printed
plt.ylim(.8,5)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

[image]

You could use `plt.tight_layout();`

[image]

Comment: What I would like to have is that both bar and baz to be inside the plot limits

Comment: Oh.. want to change your ylim?  Or move your plot text?